# Algorithm to select sets with shared elements

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, set

I have a 2d array of sets. I need to select an optimal set from each column.

An optimal set is such that the count of unique items out of all such optimal sets is at a minimum.

I am using python but I believe this should be fairly language agnostic.

My current method is very primitive and searches through all possible options this can create a prohibitively large search space. (order of 10^15)

I am looking for a less naive way of looking through the data, and cut down the search space.

In the code below I know I can make performance improvements but I am more interested in improving the algorithm.

```
for comb in itertools.product(*value_options):
    comb_length = len(set(itertools.chain(*comb)))
    if comb_length < best_count:
        best = comb
        best_count = comb_length
```

---

A bit more information on the data, the sets are small, at the moment they are two values but I want to be able to support more, there can be any number of sets in a group of sets

---

I have added created some test data. To make the file more logical, each row in the file is one of the columns mentioned above, each set is in parenthasis.

Small Set
http://www.importsoul.net/static/testdata.csv

From this set of data I get the results

```
 332000.000,348000.000
  95300.000,787000.000
  48700.000,332000.000
  31600.000,64900.000
  12700.000,64900.000
   5620.000,95300.000
  10000.000
```

I also have a larger set of input data, that has not finished running yet.
http://www.importsoul.net/static/testdata-large.csv

---

For easier import here is the test data as json

- http://www.importsoul.net/static/testdata.json
- http://www.importsoul.net/static/testdata-large.json

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sample data for `value_options` would be very helpful.

Comment: If it is likely to happen, you can add a `break` condition if one length is found minimal (0, 1, ?).

Comment: Are the sets of equal size? Are the numbers in the sets constrained to some range?

Comment: This sounds NP-complete. No proof comes to mind at the moment, though.

Comment: Oh, wait, I found a reduction from boolean satisfiability. It's definitely NP-complete. I'll post the proof later, along with an improved algorithm.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete. You can do better than what you have now, but there'll be limits to how far you can scale.

First, you can improve your algorithm by using [branch-and-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) to avoid looking at solutions that are "obviously" going to be worse than ones you've already seen. The idea is to track the number of unique elements covered by the best solution seen so far, and build up partial solutions by choosing sets from one column at a time. If at any point, the sets you've chosen cover more unique elements than the best solution you've seen, you can immediately undo your most recent choice and try a different option, without needing to explore all possible ways to build a complete solution from the suboptimal partial solution.

---

To prove the problem is NP-complete, we provide a polynomial-time reduction from [boolean satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) to your problem. We assume columns can have different lengths; the proof is slightly more awkward, but still possible, with columns forced to be equal-length.

Suppose we have a boolean formula in conjunctive normal form, for example:

```
(!A || B || C) && (!C || D || !E) && (A || !B || D)
```

and we want to know if it's satisfiable. We construct a corresponding instance of your problem. The idea is to use columns of 1-element sets to force ourselves to pick a truth-value for each variable, and see if we can pick sets such that no variable has to be both true and false.

For each disjunctive clause in the formula, we construct a column forcing us to pick one element of the disjunction. For example, the disjunctive clause `(!A || B || C)` would turn into the column

```
{!A}
{B}
{C}
```

forcing us to pick one of the choices the disjunction gives us. Additionally, we add columns of the following form:

```
{A}  | {B}  | {C}  | {D}  | {E}
{!A} | {!B} | {!C} | {!D} | {!E}
```

forcing us, for each variable, to pick either the variable or its negation. The complete table for our example formula looks like

```
{!A} | {!C} | {A}  | {A}  | {B}  | {C}  | {D}  | {E}
{B}  | {D}  | {!B} | {!A} | {!B} | {!C} | {!D} | {!E}
{C}  | {!E} | {D}
```

If the optimal choice of sets from each column covers a number of unique elements equal to the number of variables in the formula, then the elements of the optimal choice provide a satisfying assignment for the formula. If the optimal choice of sets covers more elements than that, the formula is unsatisfiable.

Comment: I am still trying to work my way though the proof, but the suggestion with ignoring portions of the tree that are obviously wrong speeds things up by a few orders of magnitude, I will try to get a code sample tidied up and posted as an answer for other people who stumble onto this.